# VB6 SCGrid Textbox

Tags: textbox, vb6

Within a VB6 form, I'm using an SCGrid object were the cells are editable by means of a textbox.

I suppose the grid control creates a TextBox object as soon as the user clicks a cell.

I need a reference to this TextBox.

In particular, when the user presses the [Left] or [Right] key, I need the current position of the cursor within the textbox. I can then simply call TextBox.SelStart.

Does anybody know how to get the control used when editing a cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

```
' Declaration needed for getting the current position of the cursor
Private Type Point
  x As Long
  y As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function GetCaretPos Lib "user32" (ByRef lpPoint As Point) As Long

' This function returns the position of the cursor within the cell currently being edited as a TextBox
' The value is expressed as the number of characters preceeding the position
Private Function GetCaretPosition() As Integer

  ' Variables
  Dim position As Point
  Dim result   As Long
  Dim contents As String

  ' Get position
  result = GetCaretPos(position)

  ' Convert it into number of characters
  ' I figured out the factor 15 by trial and error
  ' Don't know where it comes from but it seems independent of the font size
  contents = myGrid.Text(row_gvar, column_gvar)
  result = 0
  While ((result < Len(contents)) And _
         (position.x > (grid_gvar.Parent.TextWidth(Left(contents, result)) / 15)))
    result = result + 1
  Wend

  ' Done
  GetCaretPosition = result

End Function
```